# Why is my txt file not being completely read with read.delim?

Tags: r, readr

I am trying to read this large text file (~3gb) into R, but unfortunately I am not being able to read fully load it. What happens is that I'm missing a lot of rows (I get a dataframe of ~700 thousand rows, while I know the file has at least 4-5million).

The code I was initially using was as follows:

```
df<-read.delim("file.txt",quote = "",comment.char = "")
```

However, besides noticing that R wasn't loading all the rows, I was also receiving this warning:

```
Warning message:
In scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
  embedded nul(s) found in input
```

I searched for a bit online, and I found I could solve it by adding the `skipNul = TRUE`  argument. When I included it in the `read.delim` function, the warning stopped showing, but my file keeps missing a lot of rows, and still returns the same number of rows as before.

I have loaded files of similar size in the past, so I'm not sure why this is happening.

If someone has any idea what might be causing the problem, I would be very thankful.

Comment: Divide the file into halves and try it on each half and keep doing that until you find a small file of 5 rows, say, that shows that and then post that small file verbatim or maybe by then you will have figured it out.

Comment: The problem is that so far I'm not being able to open the file in any software because of its size

Comment: You can divide the file in half from the command line, using `split file.txt` if you're on a unix-alike. Not sure the command if you're on Windows.

Comment: You can try loading the file using `readLines` esp its functionality to read n number of lines.

Comment: It's very hard to help without any sort of reproducible example. Having embded nulls could be a sign that you are not using the correct encoding. Do you expect the file to have non-ASCII character? Do you know if it uses UTF-8 or Latin-1 encoding or possibly something else?

Comment: I've also seen embedded nulls when the process that is retrieving/storing the data glitches (web-disconnect, faulty logic, could be anything). If you have nulls and shouldn't, a parallel effort should be to fix the source of the data. To "fix" the problem with R reading it, though, is significantly more difficult if the file is too big to read into memory. I think you need to fix that file outside of R to be able to use it in R. (If it is not encoding, then try `sed -e 's/\x0/?/g' infile > outfile` to replace all null bytes with question marks.)

Comment: Try from `library(data.table)` the function `fread()`. I have a csv with 3GBs and `fread()`handle this without any problems. And now I'm working with a data.table with 400 Mio rows. It's still possible (even if you see a decreasing performance).